# Changing text displayed to user as a readable string when SQL data is numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm trying to change the text that is displayed when I have gridView populated with data grabbed from SQL. Currently in the database the values: **0,1,2** are stored for my entries but I need to have these displayed as "**Spring, Summer, Fall**". Is there a way to do this from the codebehind?

Here's my code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  DataKeyNames="season">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Season" ControlStyle-CssClass="semID">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("season") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("season") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
...
...
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I've tried doing a RowDataBound function but to the best of my knowledge it never fires. Or it does, but doesn't change the text value.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    if (drv["Season"].ToString() == "0")
    {
      e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Spring";
    }
    else if....for 1 and 2 similar to above.
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a breakpoint in your RowDataBound event and debugging to determine if it fires.  Also, did you add the `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` attribute to your GridView definition?

Comment: Of course I missed the obvious. Just needed to add the OnRowDataBound attribute. Thanks for pointing that out!